# Plugin allowing for artists, events and venues

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, events

I'm working on a music festival website and up until now have used WordTour. I really like WordTour's artists > events > venues content hierarchy, but am having difficulties transitioning from last year's festival to this year's. Ultimately, I'm finding I may need to move on to something else.

I need to ultimately do two things:

a. Create a listing for each artist playing at the festival
b. Assign each artist timeslots at the festival's three stages. Some artists play more than one stage.

With WordTour, I did this by assigning an Artist to an Event (i.e., a specific time), which was then assigned a Venue (i.e., a specific stage).

### Is there any way I could do something similar to WordTour with custom post types? If so, any suggestions how?

It seems like I could create a custom post type — Artists — which would have a meta box allowing me to pick multiple timeslots (how, I'm not at all sure) and a custom taxonomy for festival year. I could create a second post type for Stages, but how would I reference the second post type from the hypothetical date picker meta box?

Any help at all with this would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try [Event Organiser](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/) (**disclaimer**: I'm the plug-in author). This plug-in handles event and venues management. Events are a custom post type, and venues are a custom taxonomy.

All it would lack for your needs is the 'artist' - this could be handled by adding a metabox to an event which allows you to select from the available artists (or vice-versa).

To do this, just create a metabox with a select box, which you can populate by querying (for artists, say) using `get_posts`. The selection can be then saved as post meta by hooking into the `save_post` action.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more simplistic than you were thinking, but what about using Wordpress authors for your Artists? Than, create a Custom Post Type for timeslots or stages and then a category for that post type and assign one to the other, i.e... assign 9pm (new post in "timeslot" custom post type) to the Side Stage (custom post type category) with the author (artist) We Were Promised Jetpacks. Anyway, not sure if that helps at all, just a thought. You can do a lot with author.php and $curauth, adding fields for the author profile, etc...